# An integer value in WPF Resources?

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls

Is that possible to set an integer value in WPF control Resources?!

```
<UserControl.Resources>

    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="MyLineBrush" Color="LightGreen" />

    ??? <Integer x:Key="MyStrokeThickness" Value="2" /> ???


    <Style TargetType="local:MyLine" x:Key="MyLineStyleKey">    

        <Setter Property="Stroke" 
            Value="{DynamicResource MyLineBrush}"/>

        <Setter Property="StrokeThickness" 
            Value="{DynamicResource MyStrokeThickness}"/>

    </Style>
```

In order to modify dynamically the `MyLineBrush` and `MyStrokeThickness` values...

Answer (score 120, accepted):

To make that declaration you need to import the `System` namespace:

```
xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
```

...

```
<sys:Int32 x:Key="MyValue">1234</sys:Int32>
```

Note: you will need to use a `Double` for most WPF properties instead of an `Int32`

Comment: A word of caution: VS2015 Community does not show `Int32` in XAML intellisense if you try to use it in `{x:Static sys:Int32.MaxValue}}`. Nevertheless it builds and works fine. (haven't tested it in other versions of VS)

Comment: If you use the winfx/2009/xaml and reference it to x - you can use x:Int32 as well. Though I think sticking to the 2006 and importing this is still probably the safest bet.

Answer (score 7):

For **StrokeThickness** it should be

```
<system:Double x:Key="ThemeIconStrokeThickness">1</system:Double>
```

Answer (score 4):

Looks like the Assembly has changed updated for 2020:

```
xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=System.Runtime"

<sys:Int32 x:Key="MyValue">1234</sys:Int32>
```